# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to 0}{\ln\Gamma(2+n)\over n(n+1)}$

Tags: limits

How to does one show that 
$$\lim_{n\to 0}{\ln\Gamma(2+n)\over n(n+1)}=1-\gamma?\tag1$$

$$\lim_{n\to 0}{\ln\Gamma(2+n)\over n}-\lim_{n\to 0}{\ln\Gamma(2+n)\over n+1}$$

We have this well-known

$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n-\Gamma\left({1\over n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Presumably using the infinite product for the Gamma function.

Comment: If you use L'Hopital's rule you get $\psi(2)$ which gives $1-\gamma$.

Comment: Which comes from $$\psi(s+1)=-\gamma+\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-x^s}{1-x}\right)\, dx$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How are you to ask me that most hideous question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the digamma function defined by
$$\psi(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \ln(\Gamma(x)) = \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
where $\psi(1) = - \gamma$ and $\psi(x+1) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x}$
then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to 0} \, \frac{\ln\Gamma(n+2)}{n (n+1)} &= \frac{1}{0+1} \, \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\ln\Gamma(n+2)}{n} \\
&= \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\Gamma'(n+2)}{\Gamma(n+2)} \cdot \frac{1}{1} \\
&= \lim_{n \to 0 } \psi(n+2) = \psi(2) = \psi(1) + \frac{1}{1} \\
&= 1 - \gamma.
\end{align}